# Updating Easy Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, easypie

I managed to update easy pie chart, but I don't know how to display the percentage and update it, for example from 1% to 25%, number by number, as the chart updates. Any help?

This is the block of code where I am updating my chart:

```
var chart = new EasyPieChart(existing, {
  lineWidth: '6',
  barColor: '#fff',
  trackColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
  scaleColor: false,        
});
chart.update(25);
```

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: Not anymore, your answer worked for me. I checkmarked it. Should I do anything more to close it for more answers? @ksav

Comment: Great. No need to do anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use easy-pie-chart's `onStep` callback function, which will be called on every step to update the number somewhere on the page.

Also, you probably want to round the number using `Math.round`

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.chart');
var chart = new EasyPieChart(element, {
  lineWidth: '6',
  barColor: '#000',
  trackColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
  scaleColor: true,
  onStep: function(from, to, currentValue) {
    // Inside the callback, 'this.el' refers to 
    // the element that EasyPieChart was created with 
    // - `.chart`
    this.el.querySelector('.number').innerText = `${Math.round(currentValue)}%`;
  },
});

chart.update(25);
```

```css
.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <span class="number"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-pie-chart/2.1.6/easypiechart.min.js"></script>
```